# Handlebar template access to mongo collection.find() variable in a nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I have the nodejs express script as below

```
app.get('/approval',function(req,res){

        db.open(function(err,db) {
        var collection = db.collection('form');
    collection.find({ contact: 'James Wong' }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs); 
   /*It will  will give an output something like
      { _id: 53533045fec60bd941c04a22,
       contact: 'James Wong'} */


        res.render('approval.handlebars',{resultfind : docs});
           /*it will give an output as [object Object]

        db.close();
      });

    });
```

My console.log(docs) output is in JSON ARRAY format which is correct. i.e

```
{ _id: 53533045fec60bd941c04a22,
       contact: 'James Wong'} */
```

However when I display it in handlebartemplate by using res.render the result will be as below;

```
[object Object]
```

My template is below

```
<div>
{{resultfind}}
</div>
```

I wanted to access those object properties.

Comment: Where's your template?

Comment: Here you go .. <div>
   {{resultfind}}
   </div>

Comment: Well, what did you expect? An object to string is [object Object].
You have to print its contents explicitly: `<div> {{resultfind._id}} {{resultfind.contact}}</div>`

Comment: hmm..it doesnt show anything ...after changing it to <div> {{resultfind._id}} {{resultfind.contact}}</div>

Comment: oh I know why ..it's printed as array instead of JSON..I have replaced toArray to each functions..it worked fine now..Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it resolved ..Thanks to  TheShellfishMeme .

Two things to do

1) instead of toArray function , replace it by each function . This is to maintain json format

2) to access the JSON format at the html {{resulfind.contact}}

Cheers